# Is possible to get the current location with Firebase (iOS)?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I read all the docs and some examples of GeoFire for Firebase but I don't understand if it's possibile to get the current location of a user...is it possible? and if it is, how can I get it?

Comment: You should use Core Location to get the user’s location. Then, you use Firebase to store/search it in the database.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Firebase is a cloud database system. It doesn't, and shouldn't, have any facility for getting the user's location. That would be like using a popsicle to file your taxes. You want to use the location manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geofire has a good readme at github...

**Retrieving a location using Swift**

```
geoFire.getLocationForKey("firebase-hq", withCallback: { (location, error) in
  if (error != nil) {
    println("An error occurred getting the location for \"firebase-hq\": \(error.localizedDescription)")
  } else if (location != nil) {
    println("Location for \"firebase-hq\" is [\(location.coordinate.latitude), \(location.coordinate.longitude)]")
  } else {
    println("GeoFire does not contain a location for \"firebase-hq\"")
  }
})
```

Take a look [here](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java#setting-location-data) and [here](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc#retrieving-a-location)!

Comment: Yes I've already read them but what I understand is that is not possible to get the current location, am I wrong?

Comment: you can't get the current location using firebase... you can save it into a database an retrieve it!
To get the current location, use things like `CCLocationManager` and those iOS things...